# Total Blocking Time is bad - caused by Analytics itself?

Tags: time, analytics, blocking, pagespeed-insights

Ok,my site has a bad performance ranking in some indexes of Google Analytics.

I like to have a big MetaSlider in the top of the header and didn't find out where to put the code to hide it for subpage yet:

Www.eHealth-IT.de

But the worst Index "Total Blocking time" is caused by Google Analytics itself, cp. Picture.

Is this a reliable messurement or is the error on my side?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Plz read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to post question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load recaptcha async when the user click on email field that way you don;t have to load the script & improve your performance

Thanks,

Comment: done, problem with blocking time caused my reCaptcha disapeared :-)

Answer (score 0):

The total blocking time for desktop looks good in your desktop site. I can see not good in mobile.  The youtube and vimeo player and script load on user action will improve your site performance. To me google tag manager and analytics looks ok since you are loading async.

Comment: Thanks Sham for your answer and insight to my site It's true I did a lot of optimizing at the site which lift me to upper result on desktop in PageSpeed Insides.

BUT this is not working for MOBILE and the reasing is One and Only GOOGLE**bold PlughIn**bold - especially ReCapcha-v3:

https://ehealth-it.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/PageSpeed_Mobile_2020-09-21.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I banned reCaptcha v3 from main page and restricted the activation just on the contact formula.

**Blocking Time due to reCapcha completly disapeared**

***SOLVED***